# How do I move the Facebook Messenger icon higher in the right margin

Tags: html, shopify, messenger

The default position for the messenger icon on my site is the bottom right corner. This however, hovers over my new product filter and sort feature which is not a great user experience.

I've googled this for over an hour, and not having much coding skills, cannot find a simple cut and paste solution which works for my Shopify theme. The code from the theme.liquid file follows.

I would be very appreciate of assistance from someone more skilled than me :)

Thank you all

---

```
 <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v6.0'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

```
  <!-- Your customer chat code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"

    attribution=setup_tool
    page_id="deletedpageIDnumberon purpose"
    theme_color="#808080"
    logged_in_greeting="Do you have a question? Choose SMITH&SMITH for better lighting - rated 5.0 by our Customers 2018-20."
    logged_out_greeting="Do you have a question? Choose SMITH&SMITH for better lighting - rated 5.0 by our Customers 2018-20.">
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Answer (score 0):

The messenger icon uses **fixed** positioning. You need to adjust the bottom attribute to display it a bit above your filters bar. For that, following code works. Adding this code at the end of **theme.scss** file in your active theme should work fine.

```
#fb-root .fb_dialog {
    bottom: 50pt !important; /* default 18pt*/
}
```

Doing so, moves the messenger button above the filter bar like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

POSITION: You can choose the alignment and position of the Chat Plugin on your website, you can adjust the bottom spacing if your website has a footer.
So to change position of the Chat Plugin go to:

- Login facebook and go to your facebook page.
- Manage Page > "Settings" > Messaging
- Add Messenger to your website and click "Get started Button"
- There you can choose the Alignment, Bottom Spacing (Desktop) in px and Bottom Spacing (Mobile) in px